# How to implement recursive file list with option?

Tags: c

I'm working on a program that mimics the `ls -l` command. I also have the option of being able to add the `-R` flag run executing the problem so it will recursively display all the folders / files in the directory.

What I am struggling to figure out is how to execute the recursive logic when the `-R` flag is used. E.g `./a.out -R`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
void do_ls( char dirname[], char path[], int mode ) {

    DIR           *dir_ptr;               /* the directory */
    struct dirent *direntp;               /* each entry    */
    struct stat info;
    char path_str[80];

    strcpy(path_str, path);
    if (strcmp(dirname,".")!=0){
        strcat(path_str, "/");
        strcat(path_str, dirname);
    }

    // This statement is for the "ls -l" command
    if(mode == 0){
        if ( ( dir_ptr = opendir( dirname ) ) == NULL )
            fprintf(stderr,"ls2: cannot open %s\n", dirname);
            else {
                while ( ( direntp = readdir( dir_ptr ) ) != NULL ) {
                if (strcmp(direntp->d_name,".")==0 || strcmp(direntp->d_name,"..")==0) continue;
                dostat( direntp->d_name );
                }
                closedir(dir_ptr);
            }
    }

    // This is where I need to implement the recursive logic
    // Needs to mimic the "ls -Rl" command     
    if(mode == 1){

    }
}
```

I know that recursion involves calling the function itself multiple times until its done running. How exactly would I be able to do this when I have the `mode` which lets me know if `-R` was used or not?

Would it be possible to use recursion within a statement?

Comment: `strcat(path_str, dirname);`  Path's in most systems can be greater than 80 characters.  I suggest you rewrite this using C++ std::string, since you tagged this as C++.

Comment: Is this question actually C++ or C?

Comment: Nope, you cannot use recursion within a statement. The code in the `if(mode==0){ }` block needs to be moved to a function, and that function should call itself recursively.

Comment: So you're saying I should create a separate function I can call recursively?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, let's just keep it as a C question for now.

Comment: @MathHopeful If it's C, you do realize that my comment still stands.  Your code will exhibit undefined behavior if you run it and it runs into a path that has more than 80 characters.

Comment: I completely understand that @PaulMcKenzie and once I get the core functionality of this working I will look into converting it to C++ so I won't run into that issue.

Comment: When you have a directory, you call `do_ls` with this directory and new path.

Comment: I suggest a function like `void ShowDirContents(char *fullpath, int recursive)` that you can call from either mode 0 or mode 1, and can also call itself as needed.

Comment: @m0skit0 Can you please elaborate a bit more on that?

Comment: @user3386109 Do you think you could show a brief example of that?

Comment: I think it's pretty clear: `dirname` would be the new directory, `path`  would be the current path + the new directory and `mode` is the same. Note that in fact you should check the mode inside the while loop because the loop is the same in both cases (recursive or not). You only do the recursive call if you're currently listing a directory and mode is 1.